# How does printing the velocity in my SFML code affect the rect's acceleration and deceleration?

Tags: c++, printing, sfml, cout

I did a programm to create an acceleration simulation: when you press a key the rect accelerates and if you stop pressing the key the rect decelerate to completely stop. My programm works fine if I print the velocity of the rect (`x_change` or `y_change`) but as soon as i stop printing (`std::cout << x_change` ) the velocity, my rect goes crazy and moves really fast (way faster than the `max_speed`).

This is my code, I am running of VSCode with the g++ compiler:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int width = 600, height = 800;

    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(width, height), "Testing things");


    sf::RectangleShape r1(sf::Vector2f(50, 50));
    r1.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);

    float acc_x = 0, acc_y = 0;
    float x_change = 0, y_change = 0;
    float x = 300, y = 300;
    float max_speed = 2;

    sf::Vector2f rect_pos = sf::Vector2f(x, y);


    bool run = true;
    while (run)
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                run = false;                
        }

        acc_x = 0; acc_y = 0;

        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
            acc_x = -0.2;
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
            acc_x = 0.2;
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
            acc_y = -0.2;
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
            acc_y = 0.2;


        //X axis acceleration
        x_change += acc_x;

        //Normalizing the speed.
        if (abs(x_change) >= max_speed)
            x_change = x_change / abs(x_change) * max_speed;

        //Decelerating.
        if (acc_x == 0)
            x_change *= 0.99;


        //The printing lines (necessary for the code to work ??)        
        std::cout << x_change << std::endl;
        std::cout << y_change << std::endl;

        rect_pos.x += x_change;

        //Y axis acceleration
        y_change += acc_y;

        if (abs(y_change) >= max_speed)
            y_change = y_change / abs(y_change) * max_speed;

        if (acc_y == 0)
            y_change *= 0.99;

        rect_pos.y += y_change;

        r1.setPosition(rect_pos);


        window.clear();
        window.draw(r1);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I tried decreasing the `max_speed` to 1 ( it was on 5 before ) but it seems it doesnt have any effect. The code only works when i print the velocity.

Comment: Did you expect your loop to run at a particular framerate? Just add a delay somewhere.

Comment: No, it's supposed to be working at any framerate. I just tried multplying the veclocity ( x_change ) by the delta time ( time between each frame ) but still doesn't work : either my character goes crazy or it doesn't move at all !

Comment: That's not what I meant. Your loop has no delay, meaning the code inside gets run as fast as your computer can handle. There is no control over how many times per second that code gets run. Printing something to the console just adds some amount of delay and makes you think it works. You need to actually control that delay in order to hit a particular framerate.

Comment: Ok I see what you mean but I dont see how I can do it apart from setting the framerate to a constant value. Is there an other way given that my game needs to be played at every framerate?

Comment: How would you set the framerate to a constant value and why does it not solve your problem?

Comment: Using this command : window.setFramerateLimit(60); (window is sf::RenderWindow type). It doesn't solve my problem because I want the framerate to be unlimited ( not set to 60 fps like in this example : if a computer cant handle 60 fps, the programm will bug so the framerate must be unlimited).

Answer (score 0):

Here is more or less the structure of your loop:

```
while (run) {
    // input (event) handling

    // physics
   
    std::cout << ...;

    // more physics

    // rendering
}
```

I call "physics" everything that isn't event handling or rendering. First of all, there is no delay anywhere in the loop, which means it runs as fast as possible, and so you get as many frames per second as your computer can handle. More importantly, the physics part is totally unstable: there is no time step, so it's completely tied to, again, how fast your computer is.

> my rect goes crazy and moves really fast ( way faster than the max_speed )

What is `max_speed` exactly? Is it supposed to be in pixels per second? Right now, it is just a limit value in pixels, but the time component is dependent on the framerate: if the loop runs at 60 fps, then `max_speed` is in pixels per 1/60 seconds. In other words, `max_speed/60` is in pixels per second. If you don't limit the framerate, then the loop might run for example at 500 fps, meaning your rectangle can move up to `500 * max_speed` pixels in a single second.

Now to answer your title question: your program "works" when you print something because printing something introduces a delay. Using `std::cout` (and I would guess `std::endl` in particular) is somewhat expensive, so that limits your framerate but in an unreliable way. Your program doesn't really work, you just think it does because the printing delay turns out to be relatively stable.

In the comments, you mention that you do not want to limit the framerate. That's completely reasonable, but then the structure of your loop must change. Also, I'm not sure what you mean by "if a computer cant handle 60 fps, the programm will bug". Why would the program bug?

Anyway, the solution you most likely want is this: separate your physics from your rendering. If you want the framerate to not be fixed ("unlimited" implies that it isn't fixed) but you also want the physics to be consitent and stable, then physics and rendering cannot be tied together. You need variable fps and fixed time step. As for input handling, you can keep it in sync with rendering because it doesn't need a fixed time step.

To implement a fixed time step, you just need to measure time and do each step after another if a certain amount of time has passed. SFML has [`sf::Clock`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Clock.php) for that, though you could very well use [`std::chrono`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono) if you wish.

Here is something that should get you started:

```
sf::Clock clock;
float physicsTimeStep = 1.f/60; // 60 physics updates per second

while (run) {
    // input (event) handling

    auto deltaSeconds = clock.getElapsedTime().asSeconds();
    if (deltaSeconds >= physicsTimeStep) {
        clock.restart();

        // physics using deltaSeconds
        // for example:
        x_change += acc_x * deltaSeconds;
        rect_pos.x += x_change * deltaSeconds;
    }

    // rendering
}
```

Technically you don't really need a fixed time step in your simple example:

```
sf::Clock clock;
while (run) {
    // input (event) handling

    auto deltaSeconds = clock.restart().asSeconds();
    // physics using deltaSeconds
    // for example:
    x_change += acc_x * deltaSeconds;
    rect_pos.x += x_change * deltaSeconds;

    // rendering
}
```

However, the simulation might be less precise (more unstable) without, and might just not work for a more complex program.